# VBA Excel Loop All Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

My code below only works on sheet1 and doesn't loop through all worksheets.

Would anyone know why, please?

```
Sub DeleteValueRows()

    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow2 As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        Firstrow = 1
        Lastrow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Lrow = Lastrow2 To Firstrow Step -1

            With Cells(Lrow, "A")
                If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                    If .Value = "0" Then .Value = ""

                End If
            End With
        Next Lrow
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: You are looping through all the sheets, but your code is only referring to one sheet. When you refer to `Cells`, it accesses the currently active sheet. Don't make the mistake of trying to activate each sheet. Instead, prefix the reference **everywhere** with `ws.Cells`. It should work.

Comment: @PeterT, your insight is much appreciated. Thumbs up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## With feat. the 'Dot Issue'

```
Sub DeleteValueRows()

    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow2 As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        With ws

            Firstrow = 1
            Lastrow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            For Lrow = Lastrow2 To Firstrow Step -1

                With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
                    If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                        If .Value = "0" Then .Value = ""

                    End If
                End With

            Next Lrow

        End With

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: So simple when you know how! Thanks a bunch